# Prove geometric sum identity

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Prove that ${ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{x e^{-nx} }} = { \frac{x}{ e^{x} - 1 } }$ for $x \in [0,1]$.

I know that with geometric sums ${ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{x^n }} = { \frac{1}{1- x } }  $but which manipulations should I do on the known sum, in order to prove the identity above?

Thanks.

Comment: replace $x$ by $e^{-x}$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thanks. I tried, but than I had some difficult with the fact that the start indexes are not the same

Comment: In general $\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty}r^n=\frac{r^{n_0}}{1-r}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x\,e^{-nx}=x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\,\left(e^{-x}\right)^n=x\frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}=\frac{x}{e^x-1}$$